# Doctrine & Regular Expression

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have tried to get a products recordset from MySQL with the Doctrine ORM. I have to select a group of records using a regexp where the category field value can contain these values:

categories

> 12/43/45/101/109

OR

categories

> 1/12/43/45/101/109

OR

categories

> 43/45/101/109/12

This is my doctrine code:

```
$id = 12
$dq = Doctrine_Query::create ()
          -> from ( 'Products p' )
          -> leftJoin("p.ProductsData pd WITH pd.language_id = $locale")
          -> leftJoin("p.ProductsAttributesGroups pag")
          -> where('p.enabled = ?', 1)
          -> andWhere ( "(categories REGEXP \"^$id[\\\]*\" OR " .
                        "categories REGEXP \"^[\\\]$id*\" OR " .
                        "categories REGEXP \"^[\\\]$id[\\\]*)\")" )
          -> orderBy('position asc');
```

I have the `$id` variable and I need to select all the records where this `$CATID` is present. I cannot use a MySQL relationship and/or joins.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please feel free to post the answer and mark it as accepted for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution in my case was this one:

// Get the category selected in the products table where the categories have been written in this way: \12\224\85\53

> $reg1 = "categories like '".$id."/%'";
>   $reg2 = "categories like '%/".$id."'";
>   $reg3 = "categories like '%/".$id."/%'";
>   $dq->andWhere ( "($reg1 OR $reg2 OR $reg3)");